# What does "x is hiring made easy" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I've heard something like this and it was an advertisement. I don't understand something and I don't know what is that I didn't understand. I will call the brand name as "x".

**X is hiring made easy.**

What does it mean? Is there any reduced relative clause? How to parse this sentence?

Can I say **"X is making to hire easy."**?

Comment: "X is hiring made easy" is a very slangy, "advertising-speak" way of phrasing things, so it's not surprising it's hard to parse.  Are you familiar with the phrasing ["Y made easy"](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/something-made-easy.2818965/)?  That might help in understanding it.

Comment: __Baking made easy.__ Understood as soon as saw this. I think __"... is hiring"__ confused me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X is apparently a platform for hiring. It makes the process of hiring easy.

> X is hiring [that was] made easy [by the solutions the company offers].

It's slightly different to your suggestion, which implies an ongoing process of making it easy. They, on the other hand, claim that X has already made it easy.

I would also change your sentence a bit to using the gerund instead.

> X is making *hiring* easy.

Comment: I would add that, even to a fluent speaker, I would have advised the company that it's a bad choice and is a bit confusing. They mean "is" to be the main verb and "hiring" to be a gerund, that is, doing the work of a noun, like "REI **is recreation** made expensive." But we're used to seeing *is ___ing* as simple continuous tense, so we're halfway through the sentence before we have to go back and re-imagine *hiring* as a gerund rather than a verb. It's not surprising that it caused confusion.